# Web3j plugin for gradle task not found

Tags: java, gradle, ethereum, solidity

I am beating against a wall for a whole week. I can't really see the reason why it doesn't work. I have a project where I want to run my Java project with the following build.gradle config:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.3'
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    id 'org.web3j' version "4.8.4"
}

repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
group = 'com.suplab'

sourceSets {
    main {
        solidity {
            srcDir "contracts"
        }
    }
    test {
        solidity {
            srcDir "contracts"
        }
    }
}

ext {
    web3jVersion = '4.8.4'
}

npmInstall {
    enabled false
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.web3j:core:$web3jVersion"
    implementation "org.web3j:web3j-evm:$web3jVersion"
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.6.5.Final'

}
```

I use gradle version 6.8, since it was specified by developer of the plugin. When I try to build this project from the parent, root folder that is the root of the project, it fails with following error:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':api'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Task with name 'resolveSolidity' not found in project ':api'.
   > Could not create task ':api:generateTestContractWrappers'.
      > Task with name 'compileTestSolidity' not found in project ':api'.
```

I can't figure it out. I checked it against the build that being generated with web3j-cli, and it's the same for the configuration property (both configs have it blank). So, I don't see any reason WHY it fails. Here's the webj3-cli generated build file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.61'
    id 'application'
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "5.2.0"
    id 'org.web3j' version '4.8.4'
}


group 'org.web3j'
version '0.1.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

web3j {
    generatedPackageName = 'org.web3j.generated.contracts'
    excludedContracts = ['Mortal']
}

ext {
    web3jVersion = '4.8.4'
    logbackVersion = '1.2.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.web3j:core:$web3jVersion",
            "ch.qos.logback:logback-core:$logbackVersion",
            "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logbackVersion"
    implementation "org.web3j:web3j-unit:$web3jVersion"
    implementation "org.web3j:web3j-evm:$web3jVersion"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'org.web3j.Web3App',
                'Multi-Release':'true'
        )
    }
}

application {
    mainClassName = 'org.web3j.Web3App'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Comment: I think your are hitting a known issue. See: https://github.com/web3j/solidity-gradle-plugin/issues/44

Comment: We had a similar issue, it turns out the `build.gradle` file name had a leading space ` build.gradle` sigh

Comment: @Yuri, do you solve this issue?

Comment: @JoeDow, At the end I changed the architecture of my app so that I moved all blockchain related logic to a separate service, but as far as I remember it was supposed to have been fixed since github issue was open for a while